# Make virtualbox kernel modules builtin, rather than modules, half done

Tags: linux, kernel, compilation, virtualbox

I was trying to make virtualbox kernel modules builtin, I'm almost completed here, but at the final step, it stopped compiling, because kernel seems to treat all vbox* modules as a single one:

```
drivers/vboxnetadp/built-in.o: In function `cleanup_module':
(.exit.text+0x0): multiple definition of `cleanup_module'
drivers/vboxdrv/built-in.o:(.exit.text+0x0): first defined here
drivers/vboxnetadp/built-in.o: In function `init_module':
(.init.text+0x0): multiple definition of `init_module'

.. suppressed output ...

make[1]: *** [drivers/built-in.o] Error 1
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

Any thoughts ? Here's how I got that:

I copied all module sources into drivers folder, edit the makefile, put a `obj-y += vbox/`, and edit all Makefile of vbox modules, change obj-m to obj-y to make them builtin, pretty dirty hack, but worked.

**EDIT**

Why need to do that ? I need to disable module loading on my machine, so no modules should be present, I've made all modules wrote by myself builtin, only thing left is vbox's ones now

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Building drivers into the kernel is only a means to an end; what are you _really_ doing?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton just want to secure the kernel by making it static, no modules

Comment: Does it help to declare those functions `static`?

Comment: What is your real problem? Do you want to avoid having a compiler on your machine? How does your solution help, if you have to do a kernel-update? Why do you want to disable the module-mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I would say your question rather belongs to Stack Overflow, since it is basically a c-programming-language-question.

The problem you are facing is that you try to compile two (previously separate) programs into one. Both seem to use the same functions - meant within their own context.

My guess is that you will have to rename all these multiple occurrences of `init_module` or other functions into separate name-spaces (like `net_init_module` and `drv_init_module`). Or perhaps there is a way to declare these functions to be "local" - it`s been a while that I programmed in C...